# How to see Redash code changes right away instead of building entire modules each time?

Tags: reactjs, flask, redash

I am working on customizing a visualization in redash. Whenever I do a change I don't see the change immediately. Instead I'll have to execute `npm run build` and build the modules again. That building step is consuming a lot of time. Is there any workaround for this issue so that I can see the changes right away, and avoid wasting time? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `npm run watch` instead, which will rebuild incrementally when you change. You can also use `npm run start` to have it autoreload, but then you need to load the UI via `localhost:8080`.